# excerpt box not visible

Tags: excerpt

i'd like to use excerpts but for some reason the excerpt editor is not visible when editing posts. i'm using wordpress v3.1 - already searched up the options but couldn't find anything .. :(

do i need a plugin for using excerpts? shouldn't it be included by default in wordpress?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have the excerpt field enabled in screen options?

[image: Enable excerpt]

Screen options is in the top right-hand corner the screen, next to the help button (under the logout link).

Comment: If you need it on Pages, then see http://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/add-excerpts-to-your-pages-in-wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

if you already tried to add it at Screen Options in Upper Right Corner (in older versions)... try it:

Add the following code to your theme’s **functions.php** file or a site-specific plugin:

```
add_post_type_support( 'page', 'excerpt' );
```